# Parsing string with repeating pattern with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I read a **text file** line by line with a **Python script**. What I get is a list of strings, one string per line. I now need to **parse each string** into more manageable data (i.e. strings, integers).

The strings look similar to this:

- "the description (number)"  (e.g. "door (0)")
- "the description (number|number|number)" (e.g. "window (1|22|4))
- "the description (number|number|number|number)" (e.g. "toilet (2|6|5|10))

Now what I want is a **list of split/parsed strings** for each line from the text file that I can process further, for instance:

- "window (1|22|4)" -> [ "window", "1", "22", "4" ]

I guess **regular expressions** are the best fit to accomplish this and I already managed to come up with this:

- `(.+)\s+((\d+)\)`, which perfectly matches for instance [ “door", "0" ] for "door (0)"

However, some items have more data to parse:

- `(.+)\s((\d+)+\|\)`, which matches only [ "window", "1" ] for "window (1|22|4)

How can I **repeat the pattern matching** for the part `(\d+)+\|` (i.e "1|") up to the closing parenthesis for an undefined number repetitions of this pattern? The last item to match would be an integer, which could be caught separately with `(\d+)\)`.

Also is there a way to match either the **simple or the extended case** with a single regular expression?

Thanks! And have a nice weekend, everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex:`\w+ \((\d+\|)*\d+\)`. But imo you should do a mix of regex and `str.split`

```
data = []
with open("f.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        word, numbers = re.search(r"(\w+) \(([^)]+)\)", line).groups()
        data.append((word, *numbers.split("|")))

print(data) # [('door', '0'), ('window', '1', '22', '4')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = [r'door (0)',
    r'window (1|22|4)',
    r'toilet (2|6|5|10)'
]
for i in a: 
    print(re.findall('(\w+)',i))
```

Result:

```
['door', '0']
['window', '1', '22', '4']
['toilet', '2', '6', '5', '10']
```

Comment: `\d` is a subset of `\w`. The second group is never matched. The code is equivalent to `for i in a:
    b = re.findall('(\w+)',i)
    print ( b )`

Answer (score 0):

Not a raw regex, but another way to extract and process that data can be to use [TTP](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp) template

```
from ttp import ttp

template = """
<macro>
def process_matches(data):
    data["numbers"] = data["numbers"].split("|")
    return data
</macro>

<group name="{{ thing }}" macro="process_matches">
{{ thing }} ({{ numbers }})
</group>
"""

data = """
door (0)
window (1|22|4)
toilet (2|6|5|10)
"""

parser = ttp(data, template)
parser.parse()
print(parser.result(format="pprint")[0])
```

above code would produce

```
[   {   'door': {'numbers': ['0']},
        'toilet': {'numbers': ['2', '6', '5', '10']},
        'window': {'numbers': ['1', '22', '4']}}]
```